# Black empty table cell in HTML email showing in Outlook 2003 and less

Tags: html, outlook, html-table, html-email

I have been reminding myself how lovely Outlook and emails are. I have got a problem when my 'empty' spacer table cells are showing up as black table cells in Outlook 2003 or less, any ideas what this could be? I have spacer gifs and I have given width and set bgcolor on the tds but it's still causing this issue. I also had this when using spans to style text however changing them to divs solved this issue.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
            <!-- Introduction section -->
            <table id="intro" bgcolor="#ffffff" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" align="center" style="font-size: 15px; line-height: 24px border: none;">
              <tr>
                <td height="16" bgcolor="#fff" colspan="3">  </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td colspan="3">
                  <table bgcolor="#ffffff" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" align="center">
                    <tr>
                      <td width="60%" height="1" bgcolor="#99ad26"> </td>
                      <td width="40%" height="1" bgcolor="#ffffff"> </td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td height="2" bgcolor="#fff" colspan="3"> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td colspan="3">
                    <table bgcolor="#ffffff" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" align="center">
                      <tr>
                        <td width="70%" height="1" bgcolor="#99ad26"> </td>
                        <td width="30%" height="1" bgcolor="#ffffff"> </td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td height="24" bgcolor="#ffffff" colspan="3">   </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td width="24" bgcolor="#fff"><img src="http://www.ukgbc.org/sites/files/ukgbc/email/images/spacer.gif" alt="" width="24" height="1" style="display: block;"/</td>
                  <td width="512" align="left" bgcolor="#fff"> 
                    <h1 style="font-size: 30px; margin: 0px; margin-bottom: 25px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; background-color: #fff;" mc:edit="intro_heading">Introduction</h1>
                    <div mc:edit="greeting" mc:hideable style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:16px; background-color: #fff;">Dear *|FNAME|*,</div>
                    <br /><br />
                    <div mc:edit="introduction" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:15px; background-color: #fff;">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi dui sem, rutrum ut tristique a, eleifend quis libero. Aenean scelerisque blandit ante quis aliquet. Proin et augue odio, eget porta tortor. Fusce pharetra quam sed nisl vulputate ullamcorper.
                    </div>
                  </td>
                  <td width="24" bgcolor="#fff"><img src="http://www.ukgbc.org/sites/files/ukgbc/email/images/spacer.gif" alt="" width="24" height="1" style="display: block;"/</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td height="40" bgcolor="#fff" colspan="3">   </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
```

Comment: try removing colspans use nested table instead? see if that work?

Answer (score 1):

Outlook "hates" truncated color codes. Any 3 character code is viewed as black. 
Code all colors (background colors outside the style tag) as 6 digit/character codes. 
White = #FFFFFF
Black = #000000